# Can't continue list with except pass

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, except, nosuchelementexception

My code has to continue If the except Is assumed (them look for the next item in list) but I'm getting an error...

Tried many thinks but none of them worked. Now I'm with that code:

```
        def process_cpf_list(self):
            cpfs = self.sheet.col_values(self.cpf_col)[1:]

            bot_url = BOT(cpfs)

            nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()
            print("Atualizando...")

            for i in range(len(nomes)):
                try:
                    self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.nome_col, nomes[i])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.age_col, idades[i])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.beneficio_col, beneficios[i])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.concessao_col, concessoes[i])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.salario_col, salarios[i])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.bancos_col, bancoss[i])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.bancocard_col, bancoscard[i])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.consig_col, consigs[i])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.card_col, cards[i])

                except NoSuchElementException:
                    print('CPF Invalido')
                    pass

cpf_updater = CpfSearch('TESTE')
cpf_updater.process_cpf_list()
```

And its giving me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MOISA/PycharmProjects/inss2/cpf_updater.py", line 54, in <module>
    cpf_updater.process_cpf_list()
  File "C:/Users/MOISA/PycharmProjects/inss2/cpf_updater.py", line 34, in process_cpf_list
    nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\k_bot.py", line 66, in search_cpfs
    nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\MOISA\PycharmProjects\inss2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2
```

Here's the search_cpfs:

```
def search_cpfs(self):
    nomes = []
    idades = []
    beneficios = []
    concessoes = []
    salarios = []
    bancoss = []
    bancoscard = []
    consigs = []
    cards = []

    for cpf in self.cpfs:
        print(f"Procurando {cpf}.")

        self.driver.get(self.bot_url)

        cpf_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[1]/input')
        cpf_input.send_keys(cpf)

        time.sleep(2)

        cpfButton = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[2]/button')
        cpfButton.click()

        time.sleep(2)

        self.delay = 3  # seconds

        nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
        idade = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]").text
        age = re.search(r'\((.*?)Anos', idade).group(1)
        beneficio = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/span/b").text
        concessao = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span").text
        salario = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
        bancos = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loans"]').text
        bancosw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancos)
        bankslist = ', '.join(bancosw)
        bancocard = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cards"]').text
        bcardw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancocard)
        bcardlist = ', '.join(bcardw)
        consig = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
        card = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span").text

        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/h2')))
            print('CPF Valido')

            print(nome, age, beneficio, concessao, salario, bankslist, bcardlist, consig, card)

        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('CPF Invalido')
            continue

        nomes.append(nome)
        idades.append(age)
        beneficios.append(beneficio)
        concessoes.append(concessao)
        salarios.append(salario)
        bancoss.append(bankslist)
        bancoscard.append(bcardlist)
        consigs.append(consig)
        cards.append(card)

    return nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards
```

The page works like this:

1- If the client code is ok, the page redirect and show some infos that I can already scrape;

2- If the client code does not have all numbers, the "search" button do nothing;

3- If the client code has all numbers but It have something wrong, the page shows a popup.

Comment: Put the try-except inside the for loop

Comment: Thanks man, I'v tried that but still does not work... I'v updated the code and added the error, please take a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is raised inside `bot_url.search_cpfs()`, so you need to move that call inside the try except.  In your case:

```
def process_cpf_list(self):
    cpfs = self.sheet.col_values(self.cpf_col)[1:]

    bot_url = BOT(cpfs)

    try:
        # This is where the error is raised
        nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()
        print("Atualizando...")

        for i in range(len(nomes)):
            # You may want to add a different error handler here
            self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.nome_col, nomes[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.age_col, idades[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.beneficio_col, beneficios[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.concessao_col, concessoes[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.salario_col, salarios[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.bancos_col, bancoss[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.bancocard_col, bancoscard[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.consig_col, consigs[i])
            self.sheet.update_cell(i + 2, self.card_col, cards[i])
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('CPF Invalido')
        pass
```

**UPDATE**

Inside your `search_cpfs` method, you just wrap all of the `find_element_by_xpath` lines inside try and except:

```
# def search_cpfs()
# ....
for cpf in self.cpfs:
    print(f"Procurando {cpf}.")

    self.driver.get(self.bot_url)

    try:
        cpf_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[1]/input')
        cpf_input.send_keys(cpf)

        time.sleep(2)

        cpfButton = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[2]/button')
        cpfButton.click()

        time.sleep(2)

        self.delay = 3  # seconds

        nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
        idade = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]").text
        age = re.search(r'\((.*?)Anos', idade).group(1)
        beneficio = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/span/b").text
        concessao = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span").text
        salario = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
        bancos = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loans"]').text
        bancosw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancos)
        bankslist = ', '.join(bancosw)
        bancocard = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cards"]').text
        bcardw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancocard)
        bcardlist = ', '.join(bcardw)
        consig = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
        card = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span").text

        WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/h2')))
        print('CPF Valido**)

        print(nome, age, beneficio, concessao, salario, bankslist, bcardlist, consig, card)

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('CPF Invalido')
        continue

nomes.append(nome)
idades.append(age)
beneficios.append(benefici
```

**UPDATE 2***

By the way, in your question, the one that raises the error is this line:

```
nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
```

So if you are certain that all other lines will not raise an error, you can just wrap that line in the try except instead of including all others, I just simplified it below:

```
for cpf in self.cpfs:
    # other codes here
    # ....
    cpf_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[1]/input')
    cpf_input.send_keys(cpf)

    # other codes here
    # ....

    try:
        # This is the line that raises the error, so you can wrap this line only
        # But to be safe, you can follow the previous one
        nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('CPF Invalido')
        continue

    # other code follows...


nomes.append(nome)
idades.append(age)
beneficios.append(benefici
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Rieljun! I'v made these changes but the code is still stopping when the except is assumed... The except print is printed but than the code stops :(

Comment: Yes it will stop as this line `nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()` is not inside any loop.  You have misunderstood how your code runs.  You may want to put the codes inside your `bot_url.search_cpfs()` method

Comment: Sorry man, I'm new with coding, just trying to automate something for my word :)  How do I put `nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()` inside a loop? How do I put the codes inside `bot_url.search_cpfs()`?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.  What I meant is to include the codes inside `bot_url.search_cpfs()` IN your post (edit your post) so we can check if it is possible to execute it in a loop.

Comment: Thanks! I'v updated the question, please take a look :)

Comment: Thank you so mutch Rieljun! It made my day, really aprecciate that!